# Why a restricted Boltzman machine (RBM) tends to learn very similar weights?

Tags: rbm

[image]

These are 4 different weight matrices that I got after training a **restricted Boltzman machine (RBM)** with ~4k visible units and only 96 hidden units/weight vectors. As you can see, weights are extremely similar - even black pixels on the face are reproduced. The other 92 vectors are very similar too, though *none* of weights are *exactly* the same.

I can overcome this by increasing number of weight vectors to 512 or more. But I encountered this problem several times earlier with different RBM types (binary, Gaussian, even convolutional), different number of hidden units (including pretty large), different hyper-parameters, etc.

My question is: what is the **most likely reason** for weights to get **very similar values**? Do they all just get to some local minimum? Or is it a sign of overfitting?

I currently use a kind of Gaussian-Bernoulli RBM, code may be found [here](https://github.com/faithlessfriend/Milk.jl/blob/master/src/rbm.jl).

**UPD.** My dataset is based on [CK+](http://www.pitt.edu/~emotion/ck-spread.htm), which contains > 10k images of 327 individuals. However I do pretty heavy preprocessing. First, I clip only pixels inside of outer contour of a face. Second, I transform each face (using piecewise affine wrapping) to the same grid (e.g. eyebrows, nose, lips etc. are in the same (x,y) position on all images). After preprocessing images look like this:

[image] [image]

When training RBM, I take only non-zero pixels, so outer black region is ignored.

Comment: Please share some info on the data you are looking at.

Comment: @bayer: please check out my update.

Comment: This looks like a poor training procedure. Can you add information on the number of CD steps, learning rate/momentum, batch size etc?

Comment: @bayer: at the moment of these experiments I used CD-1, batch size of 10 images, learning rate of 0.01 (0.1 / batch_size) and no momentum at all. I also noticed that weight initialization has some impact: with weights initialized from N(0, 0.01) I have almost never seen described issue, but with weights from N(0, 0.001) I get the issue almost each time.

Comment: Do you randomly initialize your weights before training?

Comment: @gallamine: yes, I initialize them from `N(0, 0.01)` or `N(0, 0.001)` with later case producing smoother images but giving described issues more frequently.

Comment: I recommend playing around with the learning rate and adding momentum. Another thing you should check is if the features (i.e. $p(h|v)$) are saturating. That is the case if all the features are always close to 0 or 1--learning gets harder then.

Comment: @bayer: thanks, I'll try these parameters. I'm more interested, however, in _why_ this may happen. That is, I already can fix described effect by setting larger number of hidden units, but I'm curious why at all weights in random Markov field could tend to change synchronously.

Comment: If your learning rate is too high, the first sample (or the mean of the batch) will be what the RBM overfits to. If the "neurons" (i.e. p(h|v)) then saturate, learning stalls--the gradients of these neurons will be close to zero. This is one way of this happening.

Answer (score 1):

A restricted Boltzmann machine (RBM) learns a lossy compression of the original inputs or in other words, a probability distribution.

Those are 4 different weight matrices are all reduced dimension representations of the original face inputs. If you visualized the weights as a probability distribution, the distributions value would be different but they would have the same amount of loss from the original image reconstruction.